# Convergence - Notary server list?

Tags: ssl-certificate, convergence

http://perspectives-project.org/notary-servers/

-->>

data.networknotary.org/http_notary_list.txt

The site seems to be down. Does anybody has a list of Notary servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not confuse Perspectives and Convergence; they are separate programs using different notary protocols.

The official Convergence notary list is [here on GitHub](https://github.com/moxie0/Convergence/wiki/Notaries).

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Git](https://github.com/danwent/Perspectives/blob/master/plugin/chrome/content/http_notary_list.txt) or [Google](https://www.google.com/#q=http_notary_list.txt+filetype:txt&hl=en&tbo=1&prmdo=1&prmd=imvns&tbas=0&source=lnt&sa=X&ei=a1wST9K4JYjo0QGC7MnBAw&ved=0CAoQpwUoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=8b3daea88ffe5a3a&biw=1440&bih=780).

Comment: I can't add the ex.: "perspectives1.networknotary.org:8080" to my notary server list? why? I keep pressing the "OK" button, but nothing happens :\ how to add notary servers to my notary servers list?

Comment: I don't really know the program, I just know how to find data... Maybe these? https://github.com/von/PerProxy/blob/e52e0de816accdb09bcfc2f07a53a48e886755a8/conf/http_notary_list.txt